# Executing shell command not working in AWS

Tags: php, shell, amazon-web-services

I'm facing problem to execute shell command in AWS but it works normally in my local computer.
What I've used is pasted below:

```
$cmd='ffmpeg -i media/dream_theatre.jpg -r 1 media/66_dream_theatre.avi';
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
```

Same script works in my local computer but does not in AWS. However when I type this `ffmpeg -i media/dream_theatre.jpg -r 1 media/66_dream_theatre.avi` in AWS terminal CLI it works normally so it confirms correct installation of ffmpeg in AWS.

Comment: give full path for command `ffmpeg`

Comment: Please include any error messages you get in the logs about this. Logging this sort of thing is indispensable for your sanity as the developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have `ffmpeg` in the default `PATH`. Try replacing `ffmpeg` with the result of `which ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying a different shell command, but it didn't work in AWS Ubuntu instance although it worked locally. 
From a few other answers, I got to know that apache should operate as root.

Depending on your installation, you'll have to go to `/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` or in LAMP/Ubuntu/Apache's case, it was

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Look for `Users` and `Groups` in the file and change it to `root` (not recommended for production servers). 
Apache might throw an error, that goes something like

```
Apache has not been designed to serve pages while running as root
```

In my case, I'm running ubuntu instance on AWS, so I just gave Users and Groups as 'ubuntu', and `shell_exec` started working on PHP :)